# Default value in HTML select tag with PHP

Tags: php, html

is there a way to choose the initial value of a select tag from what the database really holds for that attribute?

EX: A table containing these records

```
ID  NAME  JOB
--  ----  ---
22  John  ENG
23  Alex  DOC
24  Peter SEC
```

if I wanted to edit one of these records while having a select to hold these 3 different Jobs, is there a way to select the initial value of this tag to be ENG if I wanted to edit John's record and be DOC if I chose to edit Alex's record?

NOTE: Guys I know that way that this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17076292/html-select-option-default-based-on-mysql-data) provides but I was asking for a way that I doesn't need to change the php code if I slightly changed the lower schemas :)

Comment: Please provide the source code that you tried yet.

Comment: Yes. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17076292/html-select-option-default-based-on-mysql-data

Answer (score 0):

To get you started, say you pass the query parameter name (script.php?name=John):

```
<select name="job">
    <?php
    $query = "SELECT * FROM jobs";
    foreach(execute($query) as $row) { // pseudo-code
    ?>
        <option<?php if(isset($_GET['name']) && $_GET['name'] == $row['NAME']) echo ' selected="selected"'; ?>>
          <?=$row['JOB'];?>
        </option>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
</select>
```

Obviously this contains a lot of psuedo-code for the execution of the SQL, but if you loop through every row to populate the options for your `select` you can check to see if the query param `$_GET['name']` equals the current job's `NAME`.

Comment: It might be a good idea to move the SQL out of the templating code (even if this is a simple example, better in the long run )

Comment: Definitely is @MartinSamson, since the OP didn't give any example code I had nothing to work off.  I just wanted to throw out a quick example for the user to get started.